# Fulltext search in Mysql - illogical behaviour

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm getting results that are hard to understand. I hope that someone will be able to shade some light on the subject.

I have a very simple table in mysql:

```
id| text
1 | testA testB testC
2 | testA testB
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT id,  MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+(+testA testB) +testC' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score FROM test_fulltext
```

I get the following incorrect results (note that the second row should return 0)

```
id| score
1 | 1,1666667461395
2 | 0,66666668653488
```

However when I run as slightly modified version of the query (no '+' sign before testA):

```
SELECT id,  MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+(testA testB) +testC' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score FROM test_fulltext
```

I get correct result:

```
id| score
1 | 1,3333333730698
2 | 0
```

Do you have any idea why the first query matches the second row?
It does that on both mysql 4.1 and 5.0.5.

Do you know where I can find the source code that parses full text queries?
Or any other source of information that explains how this is calculated. Any help is welcome.

Comment: You can download the source from the mysql website (just choose 'source' instead of os/distribution), the logic is in `storage/myisam/ft_parser.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is a known bug that is present in all versions of mysql.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36384

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the offical doc :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html